# How to set the default value of a dropdown list to a state variable in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, setstate, react-component

I have a React component which contains a textbox, dropdown list, and a submit button.

I capture values of the textbox and a dropdown list using an 'OnChange' event as follows.

```html
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="accountName">Account Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="accountName" className="form-control" name="accountName" value={this.state.accountName} onChange={(e)=>this.change(e)}></input>
</div>
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="originatedBy">Originated By</label>
  <select className="form-control" id="originatedBy" name="originatedBy" value={this.state.originatedBy} onChange={(e)=>this.change(e)}>
    <option>value1</option>
    <option>value2</option>
    <option>value3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div className="form-group row ml-md-1">
  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" onClick={(e)=>this.addRecord(e)}>Add Record</button>
</div>
```

And in the Js section, I have,

```js
class AddRecordView extends Component{

state={
      accountName:"",
      originatedBy:""
}

change(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
}

addRecord(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    const user={
          accountName : this.state.accountName,
          originatedBy : this.state.originatedBy,
    }

    console.log(user);
    var url = <url_of_the_endpoint>";
    axios.post(url, {
        user
    },{
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
render(){
    return(
        <html_section>
    );
}
}
export default AddRecordView;
```

The 'accountName' and the 'originatedBy' values are simply set when there is a change in the textbox and dropdown-list respectively.

However, if I let the default value (the value which shows when the form is loaded) of the dropdown-list remains unchanged and Submit the data, it doesn't trigger the 'OnChange' event and passes,
{accountName: 'some_value', originatedBy: ""} to the backend.

How can I make the 'originatedBy' attribute to take the default value of the dropdown-list. Please share your ideas on how to make it work (maybe from the constructor or any other suitable method).

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Can't we just add a check for both of them before making the AJAX request?

Comment: Even we check whether they are null, the outgoing request won't get values unless OnChange event is triggered. I want a way to assign values from the constructor of in any other way before sending the request.